# How do I use "EOL" and bash redirects to pip a snippet of code to a file using "cat"?

Tags: bash, shell-script, io-redirection

I want to pipe a snippet of code to a file, called `$x`.

**However**, I am getting a syntax error at `<<--`.

### **Code**

```
cat > "$x" <<-- EOF
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
#auto lo wlan0
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet manual
allow-hotplug wlan0
#iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface $interface inet static
        address 192.168.50.5
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.50.0
        broadcast 192.168.50.255
allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
EOF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cat < "$x" <<-- EOL
```

I don't think that's a syntax error, it's just taken as a here-document delimited by the string `-` ([here-docs only take one optional dash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Redirections)), followed by `EOL` as a normal argument to `cat`. In other words, it's the same as

```
cat EOL < "$x" <<--
```

which is the same as

```
cat EOL <<--
```

since you're redirecting the input to `cat` twice. The latter one takes effect, though `cat` will not try to read its `stdin` here, since it's given (what it thinks is) a filename, too.

I think what you want is

```
cat > "$x" <<-EOF
    blah
EOF
```